# Are empty boolean HTML attributes the same as no value attributes?

Tags: html, attributes

Some HTML attributes are described in most docs as not having a value. Examples include:

```
<script async ...>
<option selected ...>
<input type="checkbox" checked ...>
```

Is there any functional/semantic difference between those and empty attributes?

```
<script async="" ...>
<option selected="" ...>
<input type="checkbox" checked="" ...>
```

I'm asking because I'm using some library to parse the HTML, then manipulating a few nodes, then serializing the nodes back into HTML and the serializer turns the former into the latter.

Is it fine with empty attribute values or should I work on getting the HTML back into the top format above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Quote from w3c](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#sec-boolean-attributes):

> A boolean attribute without a value assigned to it (e.g. checked) is implicitly equivalent to one that has the empty string assigned to it (i.e. checked=""). As a consequence, it represents the true value.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally this should have the same effect, but empty attributes may cause XHTML validation issues, though depending on requirements/spec this probably won't be an issue. You can always check it on the W3C validators: https://validator.w3.org/